# Disable up and down fling swipe gestures with GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: android, gesture

I'm trying to start an activity with the swipe to right or left gestures in an activity, with the following code:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        //user will move forward through messages on fling up or left
        boolean forward = false;
        //user will move backward through messages on fling down or right
        boolean backward = false;

        //calculate the change in X position within the fling gesture
        float horizontalDiff = event2.getX() - event1.getX();
        //calculate the change in Y position within the fling gesture
        float verticalDiff = event2.getY() - event1.getY();

        float absHDiff = Math.abs(horizontalDiff);
        float absVDiff = Math.abs(verticalDiff);
        float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        float absVelocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);

        if(absHDiff > absVDiff && absHDiff > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && absVelocityX > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD){
            //move forward or backward
            if(horizontalDiff>0) backward=true;
            else forward=true;
        }
        else if(absVDiff > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && absVelocityY > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD){
            if(verticalDiff>0) backward=true;
            else forward=true;
        }

        //user is cycling forward through messages
        if(forward){
            //check current message is not at end of array, increment or set back to start
            swipeTo(SWIPE_LEFT);
        }
        //user is cycling backwards through messages
        else if(backward){
            //check that current message is not at start of array, decrement or set to last message
            swipeTo(SWIPE_RIGHT);
        }

        //return super.onFling(event1, event2, velocityX, velocityY);
        return true;
    }

});
```

How to disable the action from being taken when the swipe is vertical (from up to down or from down to up)?

The SWIPE_LEFT and SWIPE_RIGHT are nothing but class member constants with the values 1 and 2 respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should detect high values of `absVelocityY`. If the value is too high, then it represents a vertical fling. In those cases don't start your new `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks @jaibatrik , but how much is "too high"?

Comment: Use `android.util.Log` to print the value of vertical absolute velocity. Try and finalize the value that suits you.